# How to remove a virtualenv which is created by PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, jetbrains-ide, pipenv

Since I have selected my project's interpreter as `Pipenv` during project creation, `PyCharm` has automatically created the `virtualenv`. Now, when I try to remove the `virtualenv` via `pipenv --rm`, I get the error `You are attempting to remove a virtualenv that Pipenv did not create. Aborting.` So, how can I properly remove this `virtualenv`?

Comment: Delete directory with virtualenv

Comment: Looking for a proper solution (e.g., a command related to `Pipenv`)

Comment: pipenv is tool to mantain virtualenv. To remove it with pipenv you need to add it to pipenv somehow.

Idea of virtualenv is to close everything in one folder. Without outside records.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. So the question is why the command `pipenv --rm` simply remove the folder for my case?

Comment: I think that you forget about "not" in your last question. 
I think the reason is that pipenv is not only one virtualenv manager. You have management in PyCkarm, there is pyenv and other. And I think that authors decide for such solution to avoid conflicts.

Comment: But it can easily detect whether or not the target directory contains pipenv-specific content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196661/discussion-between-grzegorz-bokota-and-talha06).

Answer (score 5):

the command "pipenv" actually comes from the virtualenv,he can't remove himself.you should close the project and remove it without activated virtualenv